# How to repeatly use random number generator in optimization problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization, random

I am looking to run the optimization problem. I already  finish my optimization code as below.

```
expr = {x*h + 2*g*y, x + y*g/2 > B, 0 < x < 10, 0 < y < 10};
tab = Table[{B, x, h, g} /. #2 & @@ NMaximize[expr, {x, y,}], {B, 1, 
    3, 0.1}];
TableForm[tab, TableHeadings -> {None,    {"B", "x", "h", "g", "optimal point"}}]
```

However, the values of `h` and `g` should come from exponential distributed random number generator.

**In matlab**, I can do:

```
 h_array=exprnd(1,100);  %generate 100 exponential distributed random number
 g_array=exprnd(1,100);  %generate 100 exponential distributed random number
 for i=1:100
        h=h_array(i);
        g=g_array(i); 
        i++;
        <then run the similiar optimization code  in matlab as code given above>
 end;
```

---

How do I reproduce the same thing with my optimization code given above in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Look up `RandomVariate[]` and `ExponentialDistribution[]`.

Answer (score 2):

The random functionality within Mathematica is all of a pattern:

```
RandomFunction[range, outputStructure]
```

where `range` depends on what `RandomFunction` you are using, e.g. for `RandomInteger` and `RandomReal` it is `{min, max}` and they both default to `{0,1}` if no min/max are supplied. The `outputStructure` tells the `RandomFunction` how many random numbers you want and in what layout. For example, to generate 100 pairs of integers between -1 and 1, I would use

```
RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}]
```

For your question, you are looking for [`RandomVariate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html) with a "range" of [`ExponentialDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExponentialDistribution.html). Conceivably you could then do this

```
g = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], 100];
h = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], 100];
```

But, I would probably use it like this

```
{g, h} = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], {2, 100}];
```